# Bounded and sectorial operators

Tags: operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Is there any assumption for a bounded operator to be sectorial ? Is there any characterization of such operators ? 
Here, the definition of sectorial operators follows the book of Markus Haase:

> Functional Calculus for Sectorial Operators. 1st edition (2006).

[image]
[image]
I know that generators of uniformly bounded semigroups, 
 (i.e., $\|T(t)\| \leq M$ for some $M >0$) are sectorials
[image]
and bounded operators are generators of uniformly continuous semigroups (i.e., $T(t)=e^{tA}$, for some bounded operator $A$).

The result is not true in general, since the spectrum of any sectorial operator not contains negative numbers and there are some bounded operators with negative numbers in the spectrum.

Comment: Could you please clarify the following issues? (i) What definition of *sectorial* do you use? There are several non-equivalent definitions in the literature. (ii) Why is the generator of a uniformly bounded semigroup sectorial? E.g. the first derivative $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \supseteq H^1(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ generates a bounded $C_0$-semigroup on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ but is not sectorial with respect to any definition I'm aware of. (iii) Which "result" is not true in general? (iv) What kind of characterization are you looking for? Do you have any specific applications in mind?

Comment: Hello @Jochen: thanks for your reply, I edited my post by adding the reference and some pictures. For the result that I think is not true is : any bounded operator is sectorial. The characterization I'm looking for is any sufficient or necessary condition for bounded operator to be sectorial.

Comment: Thank you for your response! In your citation of Haase's book I can only see a definition of "sectorial of angle $\omega$". So what do you mean by a "sectorial" operator? An operator which is sectorial for at least one $\omega \in [0,\pi)$?

Comment: @Jochen: Yeah, you're right.

Comment: Well, in this case we have the following implications for each bounded operator $T$: "$(-\infty,0]$ is contained in the resolvent set of $T$" $\Rightarrow$ "$T$ is sectorial" $\Rightarrow$ "$(-\infty,0)$ is contained in the resolvent set of $T$". The second implication follows right from your definition of the notion *sectorial* and the first implication follows from the compactness of the spectrum of $T$ and from the Neumann series expansion of its resolvent. The only case left is where $(-\infty,0)$ is in the resolvent set, but $0$ is in the spectrum; this case is much more involved.

Comment: Just to comment on what @JochenGlueck said: What is true is that every bounded operator is quasi-sectorial.

Comment: @András: What is the definition of quasi-sectrorial operator ? Does every quasi-sectorial operator satisfy the moment inequality satisfied by sectrorial operators ?

Comment: @S.Cho: it is defined in the text you inserted in your question.